# Android Sqlite select Query if value is zero or 0

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to program a get a query that will show data from COURSE table if the values are :

```
course_id=0
or
semester_id=0
or
level_id=0
or
level_code=Select level
or
grade=Grade
```

So any rows that have any of the values above should be showed :

```
public List<Courses> getListCourseError() {
    Courses courses = null;
    List<Courses> coursesList = new ArrayList<>();
    openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM COURSES WHERE semester_id=0 OR level_id=0 OR level_code=Select level OR grade=Grade", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        courses = new Courses(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getInt(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getInt(3), cursor.getInt(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getInt(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getInt(8), cursor.getInt(9));
        coursesList.add(courses);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return coursesList;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you issue is that string values have to be enclosed in quotes. You are also not including course_id is 0.

So instead of `"SELECT * FROM COURSES WHERE semester_id=0 OR level_id=0 OR level_code=Select level OR grade=Grade"`

use :-

```
"SELECT * FROM COURSES WHERE course_id=0 OR semester_id=0 OR level_id=0 OR level_code='Select level' OR grade='Grade'"
```

However the above is a candidate for SQL injection so really you should be utilising the selection args (2nd parameter), which will properly enclose strings on your behalf. So the more correct solution would be to utilise :-

```
String[] selectionargs = new String[]{"0","0","0","Select level", "Grade"};
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM COURSES WHERE course_id=? semester_id=? OR level_id=? OR level_code=? OR grade=?", selectionargs);
```

However, it is recommended to only use the `rawQuery` method when need and that the conveniece `query` method be used. This would be :-

```
String whereclause = "course_id=? OR semester_id=? OR level_id=? OR level_code=? or grade=?";
String[] whereargs = new String[]{"0","0","0","Select level", "Grade"};
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
    "COURSES",
    null, //<<<< all columns (else String[] of columns)
    whereclause, //<<<< WHERE clause without the WHERE keyword
    whereargs, //<<<< arguments to replace ?'s 
    null, //<<<< GROUP BY clause
    null, //<<<< HAVING clause
    null //<<<< ORDER BY clause   
);
```

**Notes**
- null results in the respective parameter to be ignored/defaulted (table name cannot be null). e.g. columns (2nd parameter) as null defaults to ALL columns i.e. **`*`**.

- there are a number of different query method signatures. See [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)
- The code above is in-principle code and has not been tested so there may be some errors.

Comment: Thanks the Two codes works so what you are saying is that the first code will work but if the search is Null it will crash the app or stop working while the second code will ignore errors if the search is Null

Comment: No is nothing to do with the values of the data. The bit about nulls was about the parameters in the 2nd, the `query` method. You use null to say use the default when building the SQL. e.g. `query("COURSES",null,null,null,null,null,null,null)` is effectively same as `SELECT * FROM COURSES`. i.e. 2nd parameter as null results in **`*`** for all columns all the others defaults are to code nothing. The 1st parameter, the table name, must be provided *(an analogy if I said "Look At", you'd ask "Look at what?")*.

Comment: P.S. If the answer was correct please tick the answer as correct.